# Bower Install fails due to module_not_found

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, bower, bower-install

Trying to use [Angular-Fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack), created a new website, but when `bower install` executes it just silently exits with a single message:

```
bower                 MODULE_NOT_FOUND Cannot find module 'intersect'
```

My versions:

```
srv-node-hub@orion:~/app$ node -v
v0.10.32
srv-node-hub@orion:~/app$ npm -v
2.1.2
srv-node-hub@orion:~/app$ bower -v
1.3.12
```

I saw another question like this but it's solution didn't work for me.

Comment: Can you post your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into that. Still no idea of what caused the problem, but what made the trick for me was simply to install `intersect` globally by running:

> `npm install -g intersect`

Hope that helps.